# JACK cannot start in realtime mode despite membership in audio group

Tags: sound, jack, realtime

My jack server is unable to start in realtime mode despite me being in the `audio` group.

This is my setup:

```bsh
zegkljan@eddie:~$ lsb_release -r
Release:    16.10
zegkljan@eddie:~$ echo $USER
zegkljan
zegkljan@eddie:~$ grep audio /etc/group
audio:x:29:pulse,zegkljan
zegkljan@eddie:~$ groups $USER
zegkljan : zegkljan adm cdrom sudo audio dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
zegkljan@eddie:~$ cat /etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf 
# Provided by the jackd package.
#
# Changes to this file will be preserved.
#
# If you want to enable/disable realtime permissions, run
#
#    dpkg-reconfigure -p high jackd

@audio   -  rtprio     95
@audio   -  memlock    unlimited
#@audio   -  nice      -19
zegkljan@eddie:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30955
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 95
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 30955
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

However, when I start jack via qjackctl with the "Realtime" option checked, I get the following messages (in the Messages window) containing the error "Cannot use real-time scheduling":

```
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: Starting jack server...
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: ERROR: Cannot lock down 82274202 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: Acquired audio card Audio1
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: creating alsa driver ... hw:K6|hw:K6|512|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: configuring for 48000Hz, period = 512 frames (10.7 ms), buffer = 2 periods
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: ERROR: Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/10)(1: Operation not permitted)
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: ERROR: AcquireSelfRealTime error
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_1'
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: New client 'system' with PID 0
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_2'
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_3'
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_4'
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_5'
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_6'
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_1'
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_2'
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_3'
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_4'
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_5'
Thu Dec 15 23:12:51 2016: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_6'
```

As far as I understand, being a member of the `audio` group should be enough to run in realtime. However, that is clearly not the case here. What am I doing wrong, or where could be the problem?

Feel free to ask for additional details.

Comment: I'm currently seeing this problem too, on Ubuntu 17.04.  I'm in the audio group, but when I start Jack I see an error message 'Cannot user real-time scheduling'.  I've logged out and logged back in, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

After some time of doing nothing about the problem, it solved itself. Sadly, I have no idea what happened. It could have been some update in the almost two months since this problem occurred or maybe just more restarts/logouts/logins were needed which have obviously happened. Whatever happened, now it's working exactly as it's supposed to.